# Does ADA have a policyId and a assetName?

Tags: ada

If all assets have a `policyId` and an `assetName`, what is the `policyId` and `assetName` of ADA?
I'm assuming the `assetName` is ADA, but seeing as how ADA is the [principal asset](https://cardano-ledger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/explanations/policies.html#principal-asset) of Cardano, what is the `policyId`?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, all assets should have a policyId.

In case of ADA:

- policyId ([adaSymbol](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/0836d25ecc469d8a3494bf6db10fc8404da522ec/plutus-ledger-api/src/Plutus/V1/Ledger/Ada.hs#L48)) is an `emptyByteString` = ""
- assetName ([adaToken](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/0836d25ecc469d8a3494bf6db10fc8404da522ec/plutus-ledger-api/src/Plutus/V1/Ledger/Ada.hs#L53)) is an `emptyByteString` = ""